# Where is the documentation for MSXML API?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

Especially for vbscript/ASP.

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
```

Comment: @No Refunds: where'd you get that COM is self-documenting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764730(VS.85).aspx

At DevGuru (*updated link*): http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/xml_dom/index.html

Comment: @John, indeed you did.. i was searching at the same time.. but i added one more .. and thus: stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28VS.85%29.aspx

I found it be searching on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=msxml.

Comment: Searching? Now that's cheating!