# VBA Formatting issue handling XML - Microsoft XML6.0

Tags: xml, vba, format, edit

I would like to add 3 POI (Point Of Interest) automatically to every song I own in the software virtual DJ (the goal is to trigger the corresponding lightshow in another software)
In order to add the 3 POI, I figured I need to edit the Database.xml. I made a VBA macro to edit the file adding   tags but as soon as I launch Virtual DJ, it tells me the database is corrupted and wants to repair it, then all lines I added are lost. What I add is 100% correct (I duplicate a POI generated by Virtual DJ). 
In fact, only opening and closing the Database.xml with VBA code generates the error popup (see example below,  the library "microsoft XML 6.0" needs to be enabled)

```
    Sub TEST_ERROR()
    Set oXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    oXMLDoc.LoadXML "M:\VirtualDJ\Database.xml"
    oXMLDoc.Save "M:\VirtualDJ\Database.xml"
    End Sub
```

I tried to edit manually with Atom and it works. (This is not a viable solution since I have several hundreds of songs to deal with)
I suspect 2 possible root-causes : 
     -  A formatting when using VBA to save the file  ?
     -  A check of the database size when VirtualDJ is open ?

My knowledge of XML handling is very basic. I'm desperate to find someone willing to test it. I searched in many XML topics for a solution and couldn't find it.

Here is an example of what the database.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VirtualDJ_Database Version="8.4">
 <Song FilePath="C:\Users\jeremie.havel\Downloads\21 Susan Singer - Bobby&apos;s Lovin&apos; Touch.mp3" FileSize="1667629">
  <Tags Author="Susan Singer" Title="21 Bobby&apos;s Lovin&apos; Touch" Bpm="2.857143" Flag="1" />
  <Infos SongLength="104.071837" FirstSeen="1583844159" Bitrate="128" Cover="2" />
  <Scan Version="801" Bpm="0.525669" AltBpm="0.703628" Volume="0.464210" Key="Bm" Flag="32768" />
  <Poi Pos="0.586304" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="0.600000" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Pos="3.942290" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Pos="95.450000" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="98.808163" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
  <Poi Name="My custom POI" Pos="0.586304" Num="1" Type="cue" />
  <Poi Name="My custom POI 2" Pos="0.586304" Num="2" Type="cue" />
 </Song>
 <Song FilePath="C:\Users\jeremie.havel\Downloads\21 Elvis presley - You&apos;re The Boss.mp3" FileSize="2685767">
  <Tags Author="Elvis presley" Title="21 You&apos;re The Boss" Bpm="2.857143" Flag="1" />
  <Infos SongLength="167.706122" FirstSeen="1583844214" Bitrate="128" Cover="2" />
  <Scan Version="801" Bpm="0.541224" AltBpm="0.723401" Volume="0.540651" Key="F" Flag="32768" />
  <Poi Pos="0.158231" Type="beatgrid" />
  <Poi Pos="0.548571" Type="automix" Point="realStart" />
  <Poi Pos="1.100000" Type="automix" Point="fadeStart" />
  <Poi Pos="160.650000" Type="automix" Point="fadeEnd" />
  <Poi Pos="162.744308" Type="automix" Point="realEnd" />
 </Song>
</VirtualDJ_Database>
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling Microsoft XML 6.0?

Comment: Yes XML6.0  is enabled - I added a sample of the database (I couldn't attach the file)

Comment: What I can tell you at a glance is that the XML added to the question is not valid. There's no opening `VirtualDJ_Database` element. Question is, how did the content pasted into the question "lose" this? Did you (accidentally?) edit it out? Is this what the VBA code generated? Or...?

Comment: You're right @CindyMeister, I edit it out by mistake.. I just added it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found part of the solution.
My problem is that my database is using spaces instead of tabs.
So I figured I needed to use the "preserveWhiteSpace"property as described below :

```
Dim oXMLFileMod As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set oXMLFileMod = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
oXMLFileMod.preserveWhiteSpace = True
oXMLFileMod.Load "M:\VirtualDJ\database.xml"
```

`Perform your XML action using https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-update-xml-file/`

```
   oXMLFileMod.Save "M:\VirtualDJ\database.xml"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question will not load XML from a file, it loads a string of XML.

```
oXMLDoc.LoadXML "M:\VirtualDJ\Database.xml"
```

And since the file path is not valid XML, the result is not valid XML (in my tests, the file was empty).

Use the `Load` method, instead:

```
oXMLDoc.Load "M:\VirtualDJ\Database.xml"
```

You may want to read up on the various methods and properties. Current links are listed under [Where is the documentation for MSXML API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280856/where-is-the-documentation-for-msxml-api)